# Krita - any color space settings/profiles that allow me to have this as Chunk data in the output PNG file?

Tags: color-profile, color-spaces, color-reproduction, layer-style, krita

I analysed the chunk data of a PNG image(unknown source):
[image]
In Krita, is there the possibility to export a PNG with these types of chunk information directly in the export process? (gAMA, file gamma value + sRGB, perceptual)

Answer (score 0):

This is not even a fully valid file, the png spec says when you apply a sRGB colour profile chunk, you must write not only gAMA block, but also cHRM chunk (D65 with sRGB colour primaries).
See "4.2.2.3. sRGB Standard RGB color space" of http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

As to your question, yes, it should be supported. https://phabricator.kde.org/T1077